# TCL\Expect:: Script that is running on Windows XP is not running on Windows 7. Any ideas please?

Tags: windows, tcl, expect

Following is my TCL/Expect Script:

```
package require Expect

spawn telnet 2.2.2.10

expect "*ogin:"
send "admin\r"
expect "*word:"
send "test\r"
expect "*>"
send "enable\r"
expect "*#"
```

The above script runs in "Windows XP" machine. But when I run this same script in "Windows 7", its throws following error:

```
C:\Users\test\Desktop>tclsh 3_AP_collect_sign.tcl
The system cannot find the file specified.
    while executing
"spawn telnet 2.2.2.10"
    (file "3_AP_collect_sign.tcl" line 6)

C:\Users\Symbol\Desktop>
```

Please help me to run this script in "Windows 7" machine. Should I add anything to run in Windows 7?.  Thanks in Advance.

Thanks,

Balu P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there is no `telnet.exe` on your `PATH` in Windows 7. You may find that `plink.exe` from the PuTTY suite (with suitable options) is an acceptable replacement, but there are probably others too.

It's also possible that `telnet.exe` exists but is marked (by the system) as impossible to attach a debugger to (which is how Expect really works under the covers on Windows; this is very deep hackery and I'm not the inventor of it!) Even if that's the case, the fix is the same: find an alternative program.

It's also possible to emulate telnet entirely in Tcl code, but a *lot* of work as Telnet is a pretty messy protocol and terminal emulation is grindingly annoying. Not a recommended approach.

Comment: Hi Donal fellows...Thanks for your help... Its working with "plink.exe"